# Why are http and https protocols pointing at different directories?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, http, ssl, https

I originally had 4 subdomains, and when each was created, they were assigned a subdirectory off my public_html
So

- subdomain1  points at public_html/subdirectory1
- subdomain2  points at public_html/subdirectory2
- subdomain3  points at public_html/subdirectory3

Each had a Wordpress site installed in the appropriate subdirectory
I then purchased a global (wildcard) SSL certifcate, and installed it... so it was for *.mydomain

And then all I had to do is in each Wordpress install, change the site url and home url, in General settings, to be https: subdomain.mydomain instead of http:subdomain.mydomain

**Everything worked fine, I had no other changes to make.**

Since then, I have added new subdomians, subdomain 4 and subdomain5
Again, each was assigned a subdirectory off public_html

- subdomain4  points at public_html/subdirectory4
- subdomain5  points at public_html/subdirectory5

Wordpress installed on each.

Each worked OK when the site and home urls were http:

Changing to https: site becomes unobtainable! White screen all the time, no error messages.

I contacted the tech support of my hosting providers, and what we established was that an http: request was targetting the public_html/subdirectory4 (or 5) directory, but that an https: request was targetting public_html ! They said that I had to amend my public_html/.htaccess file to redirect the https requests, on a subdomain by subdomain basis, to the relevant subdirectory.

Apart from this having knock on effects in the code of my sites, some of which is common across all 5, I do not understand why this is necessary. It was not necessary for the original sites that were present when I installed the SSL certificate. There are no entries in either the .htaccess file in public_html or in the .htaccess files of each subdirectory that pertain to http or https access.
There must be something else somewhere that makes the original subdomains work, but not the new ones created SINCE the SSL certificate was installed.

And it is nothing at all to do with Wordpress because I created a new subdomain and subdirectory with nothing but an index.php file echoing "Hello world", and it works if requested through http, not if requested through https:

I need to know anything else that can be making the original subdomains work WITHOUT any alteration to the .htaccess files, and why the new subdomains, created after the SSL certificate was installed, behave differently. And then obviously how to make them behave as the original subdomains do.

Comment: Is it a shared hosting or a private server? Do you have access over virtual host configuration? What's the hosting provider?

Comment: It is VPS at JustHost. I probably do have access to the virtual host configuration, but don't really understand what I have read so far about it. But still, I cannot understand  why the original subdomains worked straight out of the box, and any subdomains added since the SSL added have so many problems.

Comment: I since have one of the new subdomains sort of working, but I have had to put in as the WP siteurl https://subdomain.domain/subdirectory to make it work. So, the subdirectory appears in all urls and there has been quite a lot of editing to get all urls picking up correctly. It's really messy....

Comment: @Florian Lemaitre I've sorted it now! Although I didnt have to edit the hosts file, or do anything directly with Virtual Hosts, you got me looking in the right area.

Answer (score 2):

Don't know why the Tech Support for my hosting company couldn't tell me this, it was so simple once I looked in the right place.

Logged into WHM, and there's an SSL/TLS tab. Looking under "Manage SSL Hosts", I could see the subdomains that were working correctly had an entry in the table there. Backing out, and going to "Install an SSL Certificate on a Domain", I was able to install the certificate to the new subdomains, and lo and behold, when I returned to "Manage SSL Hosts", the new subdomains were there too.

So, undid all the changes made to the new WP installs, and now working perfectly, in the same manner as the all the other subdomains.

Hope this saves somebody else half the time I wasted!